# Completely serializing an Object graph that works with any Java Object

Tags: java

How to complete serialize an Object as such it will be sent over the wire and still satisfy:

```java
Object ref = ...; 
byte[] serialized = serialize(ref); 

Object deserialized = deserialize(serialized);
Assert.assertEquals(ref, deserialized);
```

**Consider the code below as use-case:**

There are two machines, one machine (1) acts as the server, and machine (2) acts as the client.

Machine 1:

```java
@Get
public String getTransaction() {
    Transaction tx = database.beginTransaction();
    byte[] serialized = objectGraphSeralizer.serialize(tx);
    return Base64Utils.toBase64(serialized);
}
```

Machine 2:

```java
public void main() {
    String base64EncodedTransaction = restClient.getTransaction(); 
    String tx = base64EncodedTransaction; // let it be tx
    try {
        Entity entity = restClient.getEntity(tx, entityId);
        entity = processEntityOrThrow(entity);
        restClient.saveEntity(tx, entity);        
        restClient.commitTransaction(tx); 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        restClient.rollback(tx);
    }
}
```

Machine 1 is the database server that creates transaction objects (as in database transactions). This transaction should be serialized over the wire, e.g. through HTTP/REST. The client then uses it to operate the server as well as to commit or rollback the transaction in case that there have been exceptions.

*Also note that in this example, the REST client is a stateless client thus, all request comes with the encoded transaction payload.*

What would be the way to serialize the complete object graph (in this case the Transaction) object as such it can be sent over the wire like this?

Comment: The default serialization mechanism will ignore any transient and static elements and maybe more - so if your objects are using those it might be hard to serialize them completely. You could roll your own mechanism but you might end up serializing your entire heap (where exactly would you stop if you'd follow transients, statics etc.?). Also: I'm not sure sending a DB transaction to another server to have it committed there is a good idea. That's a fancy form of distributed transactions and those have proven to be a pain in the ... .

Comment: I think you would be better off investigating distributed transactions rather than arbitrary serialization, if that’s your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary object serialization is impossible.  Certain Java objects are simply not serializable.

- A (running) `Thread` cannot be serialized because it won't be possible to capture the execution state in a way that could be reconstructed
- A (running) `Process` cannot be serialized because the external command's state is not accessible.
- A (connected) `Socket` cannot be serialized because you can't (in general) reestablish the connection to the server it was connected to and reestablish the state that of the layer 7 protocol / conversation with the server.
- A `Class` cannot be meaningfully serialized because it is mostly code, and the bytecodes are not (in general) available ... unless you know where the classloader got them from.

And so on.  Since an *arbitrary* object could include a reference to objects like the above, an *arbitrary* object (likewise) cannot be serialized.

On the other hand, if the objects in the closure are all instances of classes that implement `Serializable`, you can just use `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize, etc.

Many straight-forward classes that don't implement `Serializable` could be serialized by using reflection to find the fields and their types and values.  This is essentially what Java Object Serialization does under the hood ... when you use the default serialization mechanism.  You can look at the code that implements it, and *maybe* adapt it for your own purposes.

(Not that I think that using Java Object Serialization's mechanisms outside of their normal specs is a good idea.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Stephen C gives a good explanation on what can and can not be serialized. However, default java serialization is a really bad idea. For starters it is not guaranteed that it is compatible between different versions of Java. For the past few years the most popular method of serialization and deserialization is JSON format and in particular JSON-JACKSON library also known as FasterXML. This particular library is de-facto serialization-deserialization standard. Soring boot uses it as its default to serialize/deserialize traffic for REST APIs. Here is the home of the library: [FasterXML
/
jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Here is where to get Maven artifacts: [Jackson Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core)There are tones on tutorials how to work with it. Here is just one example: [Jackson JSON Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson). In particular you will need to look how to work with class ObjectMapper - Here is another tutorial, again one of many: [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial). 
Your other option would be Gson - Google JSON library which is also popular. Here is an article that compares the two: [ackson vs Gson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson). Just another option is Bson - which is Gson with support for binary payload